# Test if coin is fair with significance/confidence of 95%

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem

Please take a look at the next $10$ mins of this lecture starting here:

https://youtu.be/rYefUsYuEp0?t=1147

We are trying to find a number $\xi$ such that:

$P(|S_n-n \cdot (1/2)| \le \xi) \approx 0.95$

The professor finds $\xi=31$ but he says that he "pretends" $S_n$ is approximately standard normal.
Why $S_n$? I apply the CLT literally and so I "pretend" that

$$Z_n = \frac{(S_n - n/2)}{(1/4)\cdot\sqrt{n}}$$  is standard normal.

By "pretend" I just mean the usual i.e. I get the right to use the standard normal tables
(as justified by the CLT).

In the standard normal table I looked for $0.975$ and I found the Z-score number $1.96$.

When I did all the computations I got $\xi = 15.495$ which is twice less. Why?

I am interpreting it this way: if I make 1000 coin tosses and if the number of heads I observe is no more than 15 away from 500, then I conclude with certainty of about 95% that my coin is fair.

Am I incorrect conceptually? Or did I mess up the calculations?
Or is there something else here which I am not taking into account?

A deviation/difference of 31 given 1000 coin tosses seems too much to me just intuitively. But intuition can lie.

Also, not sure why he says $S_n$ is approximately standard normal.
It should be $Z_n$, right?

Maybe the lecturer is oversimplifying just for presentation purposes,
and that's why he gets 31 and not 15.49. Is it indeed so?

Comment: $S_n$ is approximately normal. $Z_n = \frac{S_n - np}{\sqrt{n/4}}$ is approx _standard_ normal, but I think you have the wrong denominator for $Z_n.$

Comment: @BruceET Yes, I just realized that too. Should be one half, not one fourth there. I put 1/4 since I thought this is $\sigma$, but 1/4 is in fact $\sigma^2$

Comment: Yeah, when I put 1/2 in the denominator, everything comes out right. I get 30.99 for $\xi$.

Answer (score 2):

The lecturer does not actually claim $S_n$ is approximately *standard* normal, only that it is approximately normal.  See time index 24:40 in the linked video.

That said, this statement is itself inaccurate.  With increasing $n$, the distribution of $S_n$ does not tend toward a normal distribution--it remains binomial with parameters $n$ and $p$.  Rather, the CLT says that it is $(S_n - n/2)/\sqrt{n}$ that tends to a normal random variable, and this is because $S_n = B_1 + B_2 + \cdots + B_n$ where $B_i \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p)$ are the underlying iid variables in the theorem.

However, this inaccuracy is not fatal.  We can still appeal to the CLT to obtain an estimate of the boundary of the rejection region; i.e., critical value $\xi$ for the test statistic $|S - 500|$.  Keep in mind, the use of a normal approximation here is motivated by *convenience*, not necessity.  We could use the exact distribution of $S$ to find the smallest integer $\xi$ such that $$\Pr[|S - 500| \le \xi] = \sum_{x = 500 - \xi}^{500 + \xi} \binom{1000}{x} 2^{-1000} \ge 1 - \alpha = 0.95.$$  In this way, the Type I error of the test will be at most $\alpha$.  Such a calculation is easily tractable with a suitable computer program; for instance,

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\xi & \Pr[|S - 500| \le \xi] \\
\hline
0 & 0.025225 \\
1 & 0.0755744 \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
30 & 0.946322 \\
31 & 0.953709 \\
32 & 0.960221 \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
500 & 1.
\end{array}$$
But if we do not have such a program, then it is the normal approximation to the binomial that we may use.  The idea is that $S$ is approximately normal with mean $\mu = np = 500$, and standard deviation $\sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)} = 5 \sqrt{10} \approx 15.8114$.  Then $$\begin{align}
\Pr[|S - 500| \le \xi] &\approx \Pr\left[\frac{- \xi}{15.8114} \le \frac{S - \mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{\xi}{15.8114}\right] \\
&\approx \Phi\left(\frac{\xi}{15.8114}\right) - \Phi\left(\frac{- \xi}{15.8114}\right) \\
&= 1 - 2\Phi\left(-\frac{\xi}{15.8114}\right), \end{align}$$ where $\Phi$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution.  Setting this to $1 - \alpha$ then gives us $$
\xi = -(15.8114)\Phi^{-1}(\alpha/2)$$ where $\Phi^{-1}$ is the inverse CDF or *quantile* function.  For $\alpha = 0.05$, $\Phi^{-1}(\alpha/2) \approx -1.95996$, therefore $$\xi \approx 30.9898 \approx 31.$$

Comment: But I have this multiplier 1/4 in the denominator (which is the $\sigma$), and you don't. Does that mean my computation is still correct and even more precise? Oh, the sigma is $1/2$, not $1/4$. I will have to redo my calculations. I am not sure I follow all you're saying but thanks anyway. I may reread your answer later.

Comment: @peter.petrov No.  Notice how, even without using the CLT, the exact calculation I provided gives the same value for $\xi$.  So we know this is the only correct answer.  What the CLT says is that $(S_n - n/2)/\sqrt{n}$ is *normal*, but I didn't say it is *standard normal*.  You seem to confuse these two things.

Comment: I bet I confuse more than two things :) Thank you. I will replay the calculations and think it over once again.

Comment: Rereading your answer... Why do you claim S is approximately normal (without the word standard, okay). Where does that follow from? I guess I am missing some theory here. The only thing I can claim to be approximately $standard$ normal is the $Z_n$ and that's from the CLT which I learnt about in a previous lecture: https://youtu.be/Tx7zzD4aeiA?t=159 And I think you are missing 1/2 in your denominator... but ok, maybe that's why you omit the word standard there again where you say: "the CLT says that it is $(S_n - n/2)/\sqrt{n}$ that tends to a normal random variable"

Comment: @peter.petrov As I said, claiming $S$ is approximately normal is not really accurate.  But for the purposes of calculation, it works well because $n = 1000$ is large and $p = 1/2$ is not close to $0$ or $1$.  Once we standardize $S$, then the standardized variable $(S - n/2)/\sqrt{n/4}$ is very close to a standard normal distribution.

Comment: Yeah, OK... I see. It's OK, I am not looking for precise accuracy here... I am just trying to understand this well. And since my knowledge is limited I prefer to work with the standardized variable $Z_n$. Not sure why you omitted the 1/2 in the denominator. In fact is it that I can put any number in the denominator and still claim that $(S_n - n/2)/ (c \cdot \sqrt{n})$ approximately normal (omitting the word standard). This seems quite arbitrary to me but again... it's probably due to my limited knowledge here.

Comment: In fact is it true that I can put any number in the denominator and still claim that $(S_n−n/2)/(c⋅\sqrt{n})$ is approximately normal (omitting the word standard)? Thank you very much once again! I mean why did you take c=1 and not c=1/2 to get a fully standardized $Z_n$ ?